# Does PHP load the code inside a isset even if its not set?

Tags: php, performance

I have a performance question.
I structured a page in 4 different `isset($_GET[""])`

Lets call them

```
Menu1
Menu2
Menu3
Menu4
```

My question is, when the page is set to, example Menu1 (`index.php?Menu1`), is PHP still loading the code for Menu2, 3 and 4 even though they aren't set?

If it does I guess this is a very bad structure that will slow down the website if it gets alot of traffic since in some of those Menu's I use mysql.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `var_dump( $yourVar );` output? `isset()` only checks if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Comment: if its NULL, code wont go inside if condition. This is so straight forward. What is the actual issue.?

Comment: `So if it checks and find out its NULL, does it just jump over the code inside the isset()? `: Yes

Comment: There's a thing called PHP Manual. It's very useful. You might want to check that out -- http://php.net/isset :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say `if(isset($stuff))`, the code inside the conditional will only be run if $stuff is set

If you have `if(isset($_GET['menu1'])`, and go to `index.php?menu1=something`,

All the code inside other if's will never be run. Only the conditions would be checked.

Comment: Alright. So this structure wont slow down my website. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Never. Your code is doing fine.

Answer (score 1):

The isset will only evaluate variables, no functions nor function return values are allowed. From the [PHP Manual (isset)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
<?php

$a = array ('test' => 1, 'hello' => NULL, 'pie' => array('a' => 'apple'));

var_dump(isset($a['test']));            // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a['foo']));             // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a['hello']));           // FALSE

// The key 'hello' equals NULL so is considered unset
// If you want to check for NULL key values then try: 
var_dump(array_key_exists('hello', $a)); // TRUE

// Checking deeper array values
var_dump(isset($a['pie']['a']));        // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a['pie']['b']));        // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a['cake']['a']['b']));  // FALSE
```

If you put multiple conditions in an if statement using the AND operator, the if statement will stop evaluating as soon as it find the first false condition. In the following example foo() will never be called:

```
$a = (false && foo());
$c = (false and foo());
```

In a similar way you can give the isset multiple parameters to evaluate. The manual says "If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered." :

```
$a = "test";
$b = "anothertest";

var_dump(isset($a));      // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a, $b));  // TRUE

unset ($a);

var_dump(isset($a));      // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a, $b));  // FALSE
```